# Universal set from the axiom of universal specification

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to verify my solution in regards to the following question from Terence Tao volume 1.

For reference axiom 3.8 is stated as follows:

Axiom 3.8 (Universal specification)

Suppose for every object x we have a property P(x) pertaining to x (so that for every x, P(x) is either a true statement or a false statement). Then there exists a set $\{ x : P(x) \ is \ true\}$ such that for every object y,

$$y \in \{ x : P(x) \ is \ true\} \ \Leftrightarrow \ P(y) \ is \ true$$

If we assume axiom 3.8, then consider the following set:

$$\Omega = \{x : P(x) \ is \ true \} := \{x : x \ is \ a \ set\}$$

The following exist by axiom 3.8 and this produces the set of all sets.

Conversely, if we assume that $\Omega$ exist. Let $P(x)$ be a property depending on the object x. Then we have $x \in \Omega$.

Therefore the following set exists:

$$\Omega = \{ x \in \Omega: P(x)\} = \{x : P(x)\}$$

This satisfies axiom 3.8.

[image]

Comment: For the second part: not exactly. Assume that the *universal set* $\Omega$ exists. We use it with **Axiom 3.5** (Axiom of specification) to have that $\{ x \in \Omega \mid P(x) \text { is true}  \} = \{ x  \mid P(x) \text { is true}  \}$ exists, for every $P(x)$.

Comment: Specifically, it is not true that $\Omega = \{ x \in \Omega \mid P(x) \}$. If e.g. $P(x)$ is $x \ne x$ we have that $\{ x \in \Omega \mid P(x) \}= \emptyset$.

Comment: I do not know what Set Theory system Terence Tao is building here, but two other considerations that exist in general are: (1) is "$x$ is a set" a defined phrase in this system? and (2) does the system allow urelements (objects that are not sets)? Your attempt to define a universal set is correct only if (1) is true and (2) is false. Instead of making in $P(x)$ be "$x$ is a set", you could avoid both issues by making $P(x)$ be "true". I.e., a statement that is true regardless of $x$.